# Google sheets if date is less than today +30

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a date field cell (using data validation), I want to turn that cell red (`A14`) if the date entered is **less** than 30 days from that date to the date in 30 days time (`today()+30`).

```
=if(A14<today()+30, A14>today())
```

If A14's date is less than the date in 30 days and greater than today's date, then it would fall within the next 30 days. Therefore the cell should turn red.

I tried the above and it doesn't work.

I noticed the date output of the date field was using dashes (01-01-2020) and `today()` was slashes (01/01/2020), so I formatted the date cell to reflect slashes too, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simply:

```
=(A14<TODAY()+30)*(A14>TODAY())
```